# Quine and the problem of open formulae

Tags: logic

In mathematical logic, Quine accepted only closed formulae and banned the open ones.
My question is that why did he do that? both technically and philosophically?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Quine's reason (so maybe this should be a comment, but it's too long), but here's a reason.  The literature contains two inequivalent definitions of what it means for one open formula $\phi$, to be a logical consequence of another open formula $\psi$. One definition says that any structure and assignment (of values to variables) that satisfy $\psi$ also satisfy $\phi$. The other definition says that whenever, in some structure, all assignments satisfy $\psi$, then, in that structure, all assignments satisfy $\phi$. For example, $x=y$ is a consequence of $x=z$ under the second definition but not under the first.

Of course, one solution to this problem is to pick one of the two definitions and use it consistently. Another solution is to prohibit open formulas.

Comment: Could you explain this more clearly?

Comment: @AliDeiri What part of the answer do you find unclear?  Have you tried applying the two definitions to the example of $x=y$ and $x=z$?

Comment: First, I don't understand the difference between two definition. Second I do not concieve your example. Third, please explain the last two sentence (Of course ...). could explain more about 'another solution', please?

Comment: @AliDeiri Apply the two definitions carefully, using $x=y$ as $\phi$ and using $x=z$ as $\psi$. You'll find that only the second definition is satisfied.